# Error: load data not allowed in stored procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-event

I am trying to create an `Event` in mysql, in the Event I want to execute LOAD DATA query in every 30 min.
**My Query:**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
EVENT auto_mytable 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 30 MINUTE
DO BEGIN

TRUNCATE TABLE mytable;

LOAD DATA local INFILE '/file.csv' INTO TABLE mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;

END;
$$
```

I am getting the error `LOAD DATA not allowed in stored procedures`
Is there any other solution to achieve the same thing? Thanks

Comment: Yes, use a cronjob.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to investigate using `mysqlimport`via `cron` or Windows' Task Scheduler.

`cron` is a Unix daemon (system service) - shipped with all major server Linux/*BSD distributions.  On Windows, you get the [Windows Task Scheduler service](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd363654(v=ws.10).aspx).

(If you want some suggestions on how to configure `cron`, let me know in the comments below.)

Assuming you're on *nix, I'd wrap your import process in a shell script.  Make every effort to sanity check that the data you want to import is available (is it readable, etc) and throw meaningful errors appropriately (e.g. via `stderr` vs `stdout`, and non-zero exit codes as appropriate).

Documentation on the `mysqlimport` [is available online](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html).